# AngularJS - default value in selectbox

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with default value in select element.
I have form for create new item and update from table.
Here is my code:

Controller:

```
function MyController($scope){
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.selectedItem = null; //selected row from table

  this.edit = function(){
    $scope.enableEditation = true; // displayed editation form
    $scope.data = $scope.selectedItem
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<select required ng-model="data.ID" class="form-control">
   <option ng-repeat="option in types" value="{{option.ID}}" ng-selected="option.ID == data.ID">{{option.ID}} - {{option.NAME}}</option>
</select>
```

Default value is allways empty. Generated html in browser is:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required" required="" ng-model="data.ID">
  <option selected="selected" value="? number:4 ?"></option>
  <option class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="4" ng-repeat="option in types" ng-selected="option.ID == data.ID">4 - First</option>
  <option class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="12" ng-repeat="option in types" ng-selected="option.ID == data.ID">12 - Last</option>
</select>
```

Where can be problem? Thanks for advices.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your adding the value to the options trough

```
"value={{option.id}}"
```

This will always result in type conflict when your working with non-string values, since doing so will convert your id to a string, your simplest solution is to use "ng-value" instead and give it as reference:

```
"ng-value="option.id"
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But i must change `ng-select="data.ID"` too.

Comment: yea indeed conflict with ngModel

Answer (score 1):

You just replace `ng-selected="option.ID == data.ID"` to `ng-selected="data.ID"`

```
<select required ng-model="data.ID" class="form-control">
   <option ng-repeat="option in types" value="{{option.ID}}" ng-selected="data.ID">{{option.ID}} - {{option.NAME}}</option>
</select>
```

See the document https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: It doesnt works. I think problem is in generated html. Angular add this row: `<option selected="selected" value="? number:4 ?"></option>`